# Why aren't these objects rotating? Physics question

Tags: physics

Here is the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3k8811psg7dkq1/PackingPeanuts%202.blend?dl=0 2

I've added some forces on rigid bodies - they are shaking about but not rotating. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Better still, please edit your question to describe how your scene is set up to generate the issue you’re having - including screenshots where appropriate. It’s much better to describe the problem in the question so that others can understand the problem than to gave someone forced to download a .blend.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to use molecular addon

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this solved your issue?  To future people who may have the same problem, this single short sentence is unlikely to be of much help.